# PHP array_diff bug?

Tags: php, arrays

The [PHP documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php) clearly states

> Compares array1 against one or more other arrays and returns the **values** in array1 that are not present in any of the other arrays.

This does not quite appear to be the case.  Take the following example

```
$a = array(1,2,3,4);
$b = array(3,4,5);
echo "b FROM a = ";
echo json_encode(array_diff($a,$b));
echo "<br>a FROM b = ";
echo json_encode(array_diff($b,$a));
```

which returns

```
b FROM a = [1,2]
a FROM b = {"2":5}
```

i.e. a plain array in one case and an associative array in the other.  Easily fixed - I only care about the values so I can simply do a `array_values(array_diff`.  However, it bothers me that the documentation glosses over this difference. Perhaps someone here can shed more light on what is going on?

Comment: Tip: use `print_r`/`var_dump` for debugging PHP values. Introducing a whole 'nother technology (JSON) into the mix just complicates things…

Comment: Good point - I often use json_encode quite simply because the output is more compact.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not PHP that's doing anything magic, it's json

array_diff() maintains keys/associativity

`b from a` returns

```
array(
    0 => 1
    1 => 2
)
```

`a from b` returns

```
array(
    2 => 5
)
```

When you convert to json, the json doesn't bother with the keys if they are numeric from 0 and incrementing by 1, so the keys from `b from a` are ignored in the json, as they match that criteria

However, the key from the `a from b` result aren't naturally incrementing from 0, so they are stored in the json

If you don't want to maintain key associativity, use

```
echo json_encode(array_values(array_diff($b,$a)));
```

to reset the keys as naturally incrementing

Comment: Nice...however, I wonder where in the docs you see it mentioned explicitly that _array_diff() matains keys/associativity_.  I see nothing of the kind.

Comment: `Returns an array containing all the __entries__ from array1 that are not present in any of the other arrays.` uses the term `entries` which typically means both keys and values; the example also indicate that keys are maintained (`Array
(
    [1] => blue
)`)